# Python sockets with eventlet, recv getting blocked with no return

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

This is a simple port forwarding proxy which listens on localhost and then forwards all the connection to a real proxy and sends back the received data to the user.

The server which accepts connections and listens:

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = eventlet.listen(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
        self.chunk_size = 8192

    def forward_connection(self, fd):
        print('in fwd_conn')
        data = b''
        while True:
            print('reading data')
            x = fd.readline()
            if not x.strip():
                break
            data += x
        print('Got request:', data)
        client = Client('45.55.31.207', 8081, data) # Connecting to proxy
        buff = client.read_from_proxy()
        fd.write(buff)
        fd.flush()

    def serve_client(self):
        pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
        while True:
            try:
                new_sock, addr = self.server.accept()
                print('accepted:', addr)
                pool.spawn(self.forward_connection, new_sock.makefile('rbw'))
            except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt):
                break

server = Server()
server.serve_client()
```

This part of the code connects to the 'real' proxy, receives the data and sends it back. But as commented in the read_from_proxy function, it isn't receiving any data:

```
class Client:
    ''' All connections from Server are forwarded to Client which then
    forwards it to the proxy '''
    def __init__(self, ip, port, request):
        self.sock = socket.socket()
        self.sock.connect((ip, port))
        print('in client')
        print('sent request:', request)
        self.request = request

    def read_from_proxy(self):
        self.sock.sendall(self.request)
        data = b''
        while True:
            print('reading data from proxy') # this executes
            x = self.sock.recv(8192) # but this doesn't, it gets blocked here
            print('got x:', x) 
            if not x.strip():
                break
            data += x
        print('read all data')
        return data
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: So far the code you posted has nothing to do with eventlet. Should I remove irrelevant tag?

Comment: @temoto I removed it myself.

Comment: Please, add debug print before `fd.write(buff)` and post server output. So far it looks like server doesn't send data, client wait is proper. Usually it's because other side uses implicit bufferring, but there's `fd.flush()` in your case so that should not be a problem.